Reprojecting a SpatVector using a SpatRaster
I am trying to follow best practice and reproject my SpatVector into the projection for a SpatRaster, but the resulting reprojected object doesn't function properly. I have designed a reproducible dataset below. I am operating under R 4.4.2.
#Libraries:
library(terra)

#Make a raster file from scratch, with projection EPSG:4326:


t <- terra::rast(crs = "EPSG:4326", xmin = -124.7722, xmax = -67.0648, ymin = 25.0631, 
                 ymax = 49.396, nrows = 585, ncols = 1386)

#Make a SpatVector from scratch, with EPSG:4269:

e <- ext(-87.24353, -77.06105, 32.76981, 39.46601)
p <- as.polygons(e, crs = "EPSG:4269")

#Making a new vector object by reprojecting the spatvector with the projection of the spatraster:

sca_proj <- terra::project(p, terra::crs(t))

This produces warnings:

Warning messages:
1: In class(object) <- "environment" :
  Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
2: PROJ: Cannot open https://cdn.proj.org/us_noaa_alhpgn.tif: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (GDAL error 1) 
3: PROJ: Cannot open https://cdn.proj.org/us_noaa_inhpgn.tif: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (GDAL error 1) 
4: PROJ: Cannot open https://cdn.proj.org/us_noaa_MD.tif: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (GDAL error 1) 


Plotting demonstrates that it is no longer a properly structured polygon:

plot(sca_proj)

Error in x@ptr$linesNA() : negative length vectors are not allowed


What am I doing wrong here?

Would you edit your question and explain how the object e is created? This is not reproducible at the moment. Moreover, maybe you might want to add a proper xmax argument to terra::rast() in order to ensure the same resolution in x and y dimension - or is this additional complexity in your reprex on purpose?

Sorry, I can't reproduce this using terra 1.7.83 on Win10. terra::project(p, terra::crs(t)) returns your input polygon reprojected to EPSG:4326, which can be plotted without any structural issues. Any chance to test this on a different device?

This works for me
library(terra)
#terra 1.8.5
r <- terra::rast(crs = "EPSG:4326", xmin = -124.7722, xmax = -67.0648, ymin = 25.0631, ymax = 49.396, nrows = 585, ncols = 1386)
p <- ext(-87.24353, -77.06105, 32.76981, 39.46601) |> as.polygons(crs = "EPSG:4269")
pr <- terra::project(p, r)

This involves a transformation from the WGS84 to the NAD83 datum (even though these are essentially equivalent):
crs(r, proj=T)
#[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
crs(p, proj=T)
#[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs"

To be able to do a datum transformation, terra needs to (GDAL) download parameter  files. That is not working for you, probably because of a firewall or some such security feature. This leads to these warnings
PROJ: Cannot open https://cdn.proj.org/us_noaa_alhpgn.tif: schannel: CertGetCertificateChain trust error CERT_TRUST_IS_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (GDAL error 1) 

And the projection cannot be done.
I do not know how to solve that for your computer/network. But given that these two datums are very similar (differences up to 1 m) perhaps you can use the polygons without projecting.
